# Auto-run video files on USB drive and make the files protected from being copied

Tags: windows-10, security, usb-flash-drive, passwords, password-protection

I have some video files that i want them to be protected from being copied on a USB drive. Plus i need the user to be able to watch these videos. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: It's not. If you can watch it you can copy it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Anything that can be read can be copied.

Even if you came up with a super clever encryption method, I could always run a video+audio screen grab. I've done it on web sites that insisted on a particularly nasty bit of DRM.

Comment: Well my users are not tech savvy, so any simple encryption should do the job. Can you recommend any?

Comment: DRM...dirty rotten media....

Comment: Even using DRM it cannot prevent copying the video, as David stated if you can see it you can copy it!

Comment: @Taha Encryption won’t prevent somebody from copying a file.  On Windows FDE (BitLocker) would require the user know the password to mount the encrypted volume while EFS requires them to have the certificate to decrypt the file.  In either case when the duplicate file is created it won’t be encrypted

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to copy the video to dvd player, lock the drive tray, frisk the audience for their smartphones. Then you may be able to prevent duplication.